Electric charge accelerating in a gravitational field due to its gravitational mass and the equivalence principle
According to my understanding, in GR, locally, a gravitational field is indistinguishable from an inertial frame of reference.
However, when charges accelerate they emit electromagnetic radiation.
So if a charged object were to be placed in a box with an observer and both were to start accelerating towards a planet, would the charge not emit radiation?
This would seemingly violate the equivalence principle in GR, because in an inertial frame of reference it would not radiate.
